# uCLinux footprint breakdown?

Tags: arm, wifi, cortex-m3

Another question I have asked made me ask this question.. The previous question was about fitting Linux into Cortex M3. A few well answers proved that it is not feasible. SOmebody suggested ucLinux. I have been researching uClinux as an alternative.

I have one critical question, the footprint of uClinux. I have looked around to find a breakdown of requirements, there is no nice info on the net. The modules under interest are:

- Core kernel
- TCPIP stack
- Serial Driver
- DHCP
- WiFi Support (any of the stack from vendors is ok)

I am looking for RAM/Flash breakdown. I don't need a filesystem however there is a chance that I need it due to the driver model of Linux.

Bonus question:
- Porting drivers from Linux to uClinux. I know the memory architecture is different. Considering driver doesn't do anything special wrt memory, could I just recompile the driver and expect it to work under uClinux?

Comment: I have found some info on STM32 forums that the compressed image is about 300Kb and uncompressed about 600Kb. Ram requirement is unclear..

Comment: The exact numbers will depend on your compiler.  What are you using?  GCC?

Comment: @Kevin-vermeer yes, I do use GCC. Actually, I can use Keil or something else.. However, for the purposes of this discussion, we can assume gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that uClinux closely related to Linux; kernel-wise, it's just a patch against the standard Linux source tree.

As of version 2.6.26, The patch adds machine support for some of the m68k boards, as well as some changes to a few drivers, relevant to those boards. However, for ARM platforms, the uClinux patch probably won't give you any benefit, as it doesn't touch any ARM code.

So, the [figures given](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17234/smallest-embedded-linux-distro/17243#17243) for a standard Linux kernel apply to uClinux too.

You'll find exactly the same drivers available as the standard Linux kernel, so you won't need to do any porting.

Bonus bonus answer: if you're not accessing an external storage device (and have your root filesystem built-in to the kernel image), you won't need a filesystem.

Comment: thanks very much. The idea is to use existing Linux drivers and don't bother with porting to RTOS we use. That is why I am fiddling with Linux. However it seems the size of uClinux is prohibitive with on chip resources of Cortex M3.

Comment: @Frank - Yeah, Cortex M3 is not designed for Linux, and Linux is not designed for Cortex M3.  Any special reason you're real attached to this class of chips?  It seems a little small for your application....

Comment: @Kevin-vermeer, basically two reasons I like these chips. The ADC on them is really good, 12bit, 2Msamples/sec. I couldn't find a decent cost arm9 for my app. The ADC was really the driving factor. I am using STM32F2. However, I have to port a WiFi driver to this platform and it turns out it is a pain in the back. I am looking for an easy exit. Hence I am fiddling with ucLinux because all those drivers are available on Linux and porting them to rtos will take time.